# How can I print a NUL character without a space in C?

Tags: c++, c

I have a situation where I have to print out a NUL character if there is no action in a part of my program. Take for example the code below:

```
char x = '\0';

...

printf("@%c@\n", x);
```

I want it to print this:

> @@

but it prints out

> @ @

Whats the correct way not to have the \0 character printed out a space as above?

Comment: With null-termination, I would have thought this would print out "@". Can anyone enlighten me as to why this is not the case?

Comment: @Smashery: `printf` goes through the format string, and prints everything character by character. `%` is a format-specifier, and so when `printf` hits one it switches modes and finds out what to interpret the next variable in the argument list as. In this case, the specifier is "c", so it treats the argument as a character (which it is), and prints it (prints 0), then *continues to print the rest of the format string.* Had we been printing a string like: `char str[] = {'@', '\0', '@'}; printf("%s", str);`, it would only print "@". This is because `printf`, when printing a string, stops at 0.

Comment: Null-termination is for strings (`%s`), not characters (`%c`).

Comment: Thanks guys the code was slighlty more complicated than the example I sent but anyway i decided to make a slight change from char x = '\0' to char * x[2]; then I used strcpy(x, ""); and in the prntf I now was able to use %s instead of %c. That solved my problem. Thanks though

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if (x == 0)
    printf("@@\n");
else
    printf("@%c@\n", x);
```

It's not actually printing a space, it actually outputs the \0. It's just that whatever you're viewing the text with is *displaying* the \0 as a space.

Comment: Theres more to the code so I dont think method would suite me well

Answer (score 2):

What system are you on?  That code prints `@@` for me.  Here's my sample program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char x = '\0';
  printf("@%c@\n", x);
  return 0;
}
```

And my log:

```
$ make
cc -Wall -o app main.c
$ ./app 
@@
```

Comment: Perhaps printf is undefined in that case, or incorrectly implemented on one of the systems?

Comment: Try `./app | hexdump -C` (installing hexdump if necessary). You can see that it actually does output the NUL byte; the terminal just displays it as the lack of a character.

Comment: Sure, of course it outputs that byte; but the output in the terminal window is still `@@`.  It's the same as if you stuck a bell character in there (or anything else non-printing, I'd guess).  Dunno why that's worth a downvote though.

Comment: Surprisingly on windows a single space is added

Comment: @sobbayi, as others have mentioned, it's an effect of your terminal program, not of the program doing the printing.

Comment: @Carl - what do you mean it's an effect of the terminal program?  He want's no output if `x==0`, not output that's invisible if looking at it the right way. In other words, if the output were piped to a file no '\0' character should be embedded in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly more compact form of [@codeka's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459550/how-should-one-print-out-a-null-character-without-a-space-in-c/2459558#2459558):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char x = '\0';
    printf(x ? "@%c@\n" : "@@\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is `printf("@@\n", x);` allowed?

Comment: Alok: Yes.  The standard says: "If the format is exhausted while arguments remain, the excess arguments are
evaluated (as always) but are otherwise ignored."

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `%s` specifier with a precision of 1:

```
printf( "@%.1s@", &x);
```

This would treat the data in `x` as `'\0'` terminated string, but would only ever print at most a single character, so it doesn't matter that there's no `'\0'` terminator after the character. If `x == 0` then it's an empty string, so nothing is printed between the '@' characters.

Of course if you do this you have to pass a pointer to the character rather than the character itself (hence the `&x`).

Kind of hacky, but I think still within acceptable bounds for the problem.